# debugging integer to binary code? doesnt convert 32, 64

Tags: c++

So here is my problem, I have (what I think) is a decent section of code, it seems to work for most numbers I put in. However, when I put in a `2^x` number (`32` or `64` for example) it returns `10` rather than `10000000`, which obviously isn't right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//void thework(unsigned int num); /*was going to take this another direction and decided not to*/


int main(){
    int num;
    int por;
    int mun;

    por = 64;
    cout<<"imput a number you want to convert to binary"<<endl;
    cin>>num;

start:
    if(num < pow(2.0,por)){ /*just to get the power widdled down to size*/
        por--;
        goto start;
    }
    /*part 2 is the "print 1" function, part 2 is the "print 0 and return to part 1, or kill section */
p2: 
    if((num >= (pow(2.0,por)))&&(num != 0)){
        cout<<"1";
        num -= pow(2,por);
        por--;
        goto p2;
    }
p3:
    if((num < pow(2,por))&&(num > (-1))){
        mun=num;
        if((mun -= pow(2.0,por)) > 0){
            cout<<"1";
            num -= pow(2.0,por);
            goto p2;
        }
        if((mun -= pow(2.0,por)) > 0){
            cout<<"0";
            num -= pow(2.0,por);
            por--;
            goto p2;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: probably the comparison of `int` and `double` causes this issue. and one more thing, `2^64` which has `64` bits, is also compared against `int` which has `32` bits. By the way why not use `%` and `/` or bit operations to print binary?

Comment: This code is so bad that the best thing I can suggest is that you get a decent book and go through it. You shouldn't be using gotos at all, and there's no need to use the pow function to generate powers of 2, which is usually done with the shift operator: `1 << (por - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, some important details

- Uses only int; using doubles is unnecessary and a source of possible error
- Loop size based on sizeof.
- Makes use of 0 == false, everything else == true.  Simply masking the bit in question avoids the need to worry about the implementation specific behavior of right-shifting a signed value with the highest order bit set.
- Doesn't use goto.  Yea, goto is in the language, but only YACC can get away with it, people should not use it.

#### Source

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   int num;

   cout << "input a number you want to convert to binary" << endl;
   cin >> num;

   for(int j = sizeof(num)*8 - 1;j >= 0;j--)
   {
      if(num & (0x1 << j)) cout << "1";
      else cout << "0";
   }
   cout << endl;
   return 0;
}
```